# How to decide whether PDE is Homogeneous or non-homogeneous.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, self-learning

I am studying second order PDE.

And I have seen homogeneous and non-homogeneous PDE.

But I cannot decide which one is homogeneous or non-homogeneous.

For examples;

(1)  $(D^3-3D^2D'+4D'^3)u=0$

The equation is said to be homogeneous. Why?

(2) $x^2u_{xx}-y^2u_{yy}2xu_x+2yu_y=0$

Homogeneous or nonhomogeneous? Why?

(3) $x^2u_{xx}-y^2u_{yy}=xy$

Homogeneous or nonhomogeneous? Why?

I wrote some examples just because you can explain more efficiently. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that $u$ solves the PDE and check whether every function $\alpha u$ solves it too. If they do, the PDE is homogeneous, otherwise it is not.

The method is quite easy and short. In case (2) for example, the LHS for $\alpha u$ becomes
$$\alpha x^2u_{xx}-\alpha^2y^2u_{yy}2xu_x+2\alpha yu_y=\alpha (x^2u_{xx}-y^2u_{yy}2xu_x+2yu_y)+(\alpha-\alpha^2)y^2u_{yy}2xu_x,
$$
which is, if $u$ solves the PDE and for every $\alpha$ not $0$ or $1$, a nonzero multiple of
$$
y^2u_{yy}2xu_x,
$$
not always zero, hence the PDE is not homogeneous. Likewise, the LHS of (3) becomes 
$$
\alpha(x^2u_{xx}-y^2u_{yy}),
$$
hence, if $u$ solves the PDE, $\alpha u$ solves the PDE if, for every $(x,y)$,
$$
\alpha xy=xy.
$$
This is obviously false hence (3) is not homogeneous. And so on.

Comment: But the way is too difficult and long. In order to decide which method the equation can be solved, I want to learn how to decide non-homogenous or homogeneous. By the way, I read a statement. Accourding to the statement, " in order to be homogeneous linear PDE, all the terms containing derivatives should be of the same order" Thus, the first example I wrote said to be homogeneous PDE. But I cannot understand the statement precisely and correctly. Please explain a little bit. I am a new learner of PDE. And I have difficult. :(

Comment: This is not so, actually the method is instantaneous. See expanded version.

Answer (score 1):

Eqs. (1) and (2) are of the form
$$
\mathcal{D} u = 0
$$
where $\mathcal D$ is a differential operator. Thus, these differential equations are homogeneous. Eq. (3), of the form
$$
\mathcal{D} u = f \neq 0
$$
is non-homogeneous. The definition of homogeneity as a [multiplicative scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) in @Did's answer isn't very common in the context of PDE. However, it works at least for linear differential operators $\mathcal D$. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3081158/418542).