# Regarding the PDE $ u_{tt}+u_{xxxx} + \cos x \cos u = 0$, which of the statements is correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the partial differential equation $\quad$ $ u_{tt}+u_{xxxx} + \cos x \cos u = 0$.

Which of the following statements is correct?

- Let $ L u = u_{tt}+u_{xxxx} + \cos x \cos u $. So, the PDE can be written as $ L u = 0 $ and therefore, it is homogeneous.
- Let $ L u = u_{tt}+u_{xxxx} $. So, the PDE can be written as $ L u = - \cos x \cos u  $ and therefore, it is not homogeneous.

I think the second one is the right one. Could you explain a little?

Also the partial differential equation is semilinear and therefore it is also quasi-linear. Is this correct?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597962/how-to-decide-whether-pde-is-homogeneous-or-non-homogeneous

Comment: for the second part: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839532/difference-between-second-order-quasi-linear-and-semi-linear-pde

Comment: $\cos u$ is not a linear operator