# Is $u_{t}+u^2u_x=\sin(u)$ homogeneous?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology, homogeneous-equation

I am wondering if the PDE $u_{t}+u^2u_x=\sin(u)$ is homogeneous.

The constant $u=0$ satisfies the equation so I think it is homogeneous? There does seem to be other definitions of homogeneity online that I’ve not encountered, such as every multiple of a solution is also a solution, so I am not clear on this? Also would the equation be classed as 'Non-linear' or 'Quasi-linear'?

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597962/how-to-decide-whether-pde-is-homogeneous-or-non-homogeneous) we have the definition that if $u$ is a solution then $\alpha u$ must be a solution.

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081158/partial-differential-equations-question-state-if-the-following-pdes-are-linear) in the 4th example, this definition wouldn’t hold, but it is said to be homogeneous.

This is where there is confusion.

Comment: This is a first-order quasi-linear PDE, hence a nonlinear PDE. Since it is of the form $\mathcal{D} u = 0$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is a nonlinear differential operator, it will be called homogeneous. The definition of homogeneity "$u$ solution $\implies \alpha u$ solution" as [multiplicative scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) is correct for linear operators $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: @EditPiAf thank you for your help (the answer is now deleted). Would this mean that the equation $u_t+u^2u_x=\cos(u)$ is homogeneous too as it can be written in the form $\mathcal{D}u=0$ for a non-linear operator $\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: Yes, that's it!